# How to sort a string array by numeric style?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, sorting

I have a filenames array, I want to sort it by numeric style, please give to me a solution.

**Example1:**

Original array: `[name99.txt, name98.txt, name100.txt]`
Sorted array: `[name98.txt, name99.txt, name100.txt]`
(Using string sorting, result of sorting is `[name100.txt, name98.txt, name99.txt]`)

**Example2:**

Original array: `[a99.txt, b98.txt, b100.txt]`
Sorted array: `[a99.txt, b98.txt, b100.txt]`
(Using string sorting, result of sorting is `[a99.txt, b100.txt, b99.txt]`)

Comment: What have you tried? Obviously it will sort alphanumeric by default, but have you tried writing a custom comparer, for example?

Comment: Your question is confusing because you don't explain **what you get** and **what you want to get**. What is “sorted array”, what is “result of sorting using string sorting”? Communicate your thoughts clearly, and you'll get good answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
string[] ar = new string[] { "name99.txt", "name98.txt", "name100.txt" };
Array.Sort(ar, (a, b) => int.Parse(Regex.Replace(a, "[^0-9]", "")) - int.Parse(Regex.Replace(b, "[^0-9]", "")));

foreach (var a in ar)
    Console.WriteLine(a);
```

The above assumed that your files are allways called `name###.txt`. For the real numeric sorting use the following more complicated version:

```
public static void NumericalSort(string[] ar)
{
    Regex rgx = new Regex("([^0-9]*)([0-9]+)");
    Array.Sort(ar, (a, b) =>
    {
        var ma = rgx.Matches(a);
        var mb = rgx.Matches(b);
        for (int i = 0; i < ma.Count; ++i)
        {
            int ret = ma[i].Groups[1].Value.CompareTo(mb[i].Groups[1].Value);
            if (ret != 0)
                return ret;

            ret = int.Parse(ma[i].Groups[2].Value) - int.Parse(mb[i].Groups[2].Value);
            if (ret != 0)
                return ret;
        }

        return 0;
    });
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] ar = new string[] { "a99.txt", "b98.txt", "b100.txt" };

    NumericalSort(ar);

    foreach (var a in ar)
        Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

Comment: Great Petar! But, what you think about my "Example 2"

Comment: Just posted an implementation of the true numeric sorting - it will cover your second example.

Comment: Just noting that in production code, I would extract this in a separate method (and class, probably). It is not immediately obvious what it does, at all.

Comment: @Dan There's just no pleasing some people. First you complain about your inability to look things up on MSDN. Now you are whining about not being able to understand a .net implementation.

Comment: @David: Yeah, I'm a picky type. Sometimes this leads to answers being improved, which is the purpose of comments on StackExchange, I suppose. In my opinion, a perfect answer would contain an implementation of `IComparer` called `FilenameComparer` with this code inside. This would prove both easily maintainable and stable.

Answer (score 4):

There may well be a managed way to do this, but I would probably just P/invoke to [`StrCmpLogicalW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759947%28VS.85%29.aspx).

```
[DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling=true)]
static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(String x, String y);
```

If you use this function, rather than rolling your own comparison function, you'll get the same behaviour as Explorer and other system components that use logical comparison.

Note, however, that this will not work in environments where WinAPI is inaccessible (such as Windows Phone, Mono or Silverlight), [might work differently on different systems](http://www.siao2.com/2006/10/01/778990.aspx) and should be decorated with a comment so the future maintainer of your code knows why P/Invoke is used for sorting.

Comment: Nice. didn't know that call existed.

Comment: I wouldn't use WinAPI for string comparison. Firstly, it ties code to a very particular platform (I'm not even talking Mono here—think Silverlight, Windows Phone). Secondly, **we are not even interoperating with Windows**. I understand calling WinAPI for handling complex corner cases with window control drawing in Windows Forms, or doing some real low-level stuff. But come on, *compare strings with WinAPI*? As a .NET developer, I have *no idea* what `StrCmpLogicalW` does and even if `shlwapi.dll` exists on all systems we want target.

Comment: What I'm basically saying is, by using this call you obligate future developers to spend 10 minutes of their time researching WinAPI documentation (btw, it's in C) and more time debugging it when something *does* go wrong (e.g. function result might depend on Regional Settings, the library may not exist on some systems, et cetera).

Comment: @David: sure. I just wanted to point out what I think is wrong with this approach.

Comment: why not add those points in an edit to the answer. That's just a bit more constructive than a downvote.

Comment: @David: You're right I should've done precisely that instead of writing a comment. I also removed the downvote.

Comment: I'm looking for functionality similar to how Windows Explorer orders strings (well, filenames, actually), and so at first `StrCmpLogicalW` looks great, with the caveats @DanAbramov mentioned. But then I noticed that with this function, there's no way to pass in an arbitrary culture. And most importantly, the warning in the MSDN documentation: "**Note:**  Behavior of this function, and therefore the results it returns, can change from release to release. _It should not be used for canonical sorting applications_" (emphasis mine). That's a deal-breaker for me!

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be found here: [Alphanumeric Sorting](http://www.dotnetperls.com/alphanumeric-sorting)

Comment: Alphanumeric sorting is the norm... I could be wrong, but I think that is the wrong term here.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is good when the length of the numeric chunks is no longer than 9 digits:

```
private string[] NumericalSort(IEnumerable<string> list)
{
    var ar = list.ToArray();

    Array.Sort(ar, (a, b) =>
    {
        var aa = Regex.Replace(a, @"\d+", m => m.Value.PadLeft(9, '0'));
        var bb = Regex.Replace(b, @"\d+", m => m.Value.PadLeft(9, '0'));
        
        return string.Compare(aa, bb);
    });

    return ar;
}
```