# How to sort an array of string representing numbers (positive and negative as well as having a decimal part)?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, numbers

With Windows form application, I select a txt file with random numerical values and I can print it on the screen properly. But "Array.Sort (values)" didn't work when I wanted to sort the values. How can I handle this?

Button Click Function

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            InitialDirectory = @"C:\",
            Title = "Title",
            CheckFileExists = true,
            CheckPathExists = true,
            DefaultExt = "txt",
            Filter = "txt (*.txt)|*.txt",
            FilterIndex = 2,
            RestoreDirectory = true,
            ReadOnlyChecked = true,
            ShowReadOnly = true
        };
        if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string path = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            string[] txtDoc = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            textBox6.Text = path;
            Array.Sort(txtDoc);
            foreach (string s in txtDoc)
            {
                txtDoc = s.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                foreach (string ss in txtDoc)
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text +=ss+"\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

OUTPUT

```
10
2
5
-4
12,37
2
69
45
-4,41
35
76
35
-45
6
10
5
4
12
78
25
1
```

Sample txt

```
10 2 5   -4  

6 10    5    4 12   
35 -45
12,37


2 69 45   -4,41 
35  76
78  25    1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array.Sort for strings with numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796494/array-sort-for-strings-with-numbers) and [How to sort a string array by numeric style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723487/how-to-sort-a-string-array-by-numeric-style)

Comment: Your sort is not going to be numeric, as you're performing it on an array of strings, not an array of numbers.

Comment: Why do you have a plus sign at the end? richTextBox1.Text +=ss+

Comment: Also, your array doesn't represent the actual output you want.  To get that, you're going to have to do the `Split` thing on the array first, and then perform your sort.

Comment: @jdweng: They're concatenating a newline.

Comment: Yes, I guess each line is a separate index. How can I separate each number? @TimSchmelter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could sort the numbers with LINQ and parse them with `double.TryParse`(it seems you use comma as decimal separator):

```
string[] sortedNumbers = txtDoc
    .SelectMany(line => line
        .Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(token => double.TryParse(token, out double value) ? value : (double?)null)
        .Where(nullableDouble => nullableDouble.HasValue)
        .Select(nullableDouble => nullableDouble.Value))
    .OrderBy(value => value)
    .Select(value => value.ToString())
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you for help. But I updated it like this because it gave an error in line 3. `Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: @chapter: ok, that works too, but you have noticed that i was using a `char` not a `string` as first parameter? That overload of `String.Split` exists: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0#System_String_Split_System_Char_System_StringSplitOptions_

Answer (score 1):

`Array.Sort()` is not working because you are trying to sort by `string` i.e trying to sort lines present in the text file instead of sorting all integers present in that file.

To solve your problem,

1. You need to read all lines from your file, This step is already done in your code.
2. Split each line by  , then convert all strings into an array of double.
3. Then Sort it in ascending order.
4. Now update your `richTextBox1`

---

```
string[] txtDoc = File.ReadAllLines(path);
var sortedList = new List<double>();
foreach(var line in txtDoc)
{
     var value = line.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                       .Select(double.Parse)
                       .ToList()
     sortedList.AddRange(value);
}

sortedList.Sort();
richTextBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, sortedList);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Your code works fine but I guess you should write foreach instead of for :)

Answer (score 0):

if txtDoc is an array that contains all your strings, you may order it this way:

```
string[] orderedList = 
  txtDoc.OrderBy(x => new string(x.Where(char.IsNumber).ToArray())).ToArray();
```